# How do I scrape the date links off this website: https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/activity?inputSelect=registration&registration=N12345

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to print the dates which come up as a list of links at the bottom of this website. I do not know what is going wrong as no errors flash up. I have tried simpler approaches which work for websites such as the NY times to retrieve all their hrefs. However these did not work and so I looked into User Agent.

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
import urllib2
from urllib import URLopener

URLopener.version
from urllib import FancyURLopener
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
MyOpener.version
myopener = MyOpener()
page = myopener.open('https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/activity?inputSelect=registration&registration=N12345')  
page.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for line in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(line.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the below script. It will give you all the desired links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

page_url = "https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/activity?inputSelect=registration&registration=N12345"
page = requests.get(page_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for items in soup.select(".dates"):
    print(urljoin(page_url,items['href']))
```

Partial output:

```
https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/map?icao=A061D9&date=2017-11-14
https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/map?icao=A061D9&date=2017-11-09
https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/map?icao=A061D9&date=2017-11-08
https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/map?icao=A061D9&date=2017-11-05
https://flight-data.adsbexchange.com/map?icao=A061D9&date=2017-10-31
```

Comment: Thank you Sachin for python 2.7 it should be

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urlparse import urljoin
    import requests